# DataFrame.combine example

Tags: python, pandas

I've read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html?highlight=combine#pandas.DataFrame.combine) but can't wrap my head around the `func` argument, what's it for? and how is this different from combine_first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func` takes two series, and returns a series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# This will add the 'a' columns.
>> pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4), 'b': range(2, 6)}).\
    combine(pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1, 5)}), func=lambda a, b: a + b)
       a   b
0  1 NaN
1  3 NaN
2  5 NaN
3  7 NaN
```

(FWIW, I don't think this is particularly well documented.)